# undefined method for #<Array:0x7feb70d56fe8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want show all price for all finds days.

**in controller view**

```
def view
 @travel = Travel.find(params[:id])
 @car = Car.find(:first, :conditions => ["id = ?", @travel.car_id])
 @start_day = StartDay.find(:all, :conditions => ["travel_id = ?", @travel.id])
 @import_price = ImportPrice.find(:all, 
        :conditions => ["begin_date = ? and car_code = ?",
                        @start_day.day, @car.short_name])
end
```

When I add value @import_price appears error:

```
undefined method `day' for #<Array:0x7feb70d56fe8>
```

How me make the correct selection for all days?

Thanks in advance.

ruby 1.8.7 rails 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes because your @start_day object is returning an array. if you want to fetch the day field data, you can do like this:

```
def view
 @travel = Travel.find(params[:id])
 @car = Car.find(:first, :conditions => ["id = ?", @travel.car_id])
 @start_day = StartDay.find(:all, :conditions => ["travel_id = ?", @travel.id])
 @import_price = ImportPrice.find(:all, 
        :conditions => ["begin_date in ? and car_code = ?",
                        @start_day.map{|x| x.day}, @car.short_name])
end
```

or

```
def view
 @travel = Travel.find(params[:id])
 @car = Car.find(:first, :conditions => ["id = ?", @travel.car_id])
 @start_day = StartDay.find(:first, :conditions => ["travel_id = ?", @travel.id])
 @import_price = ImportPrice.find(:all, 
        :conditions => ["begin_date = ? and car_code = ?",
                        @start_day.day}, @car.short_name])
end
```

Comment: I think that there should be: @import_price = ImportPrice.where('begin_date IN (?) and car_code = ?', @start_day.map(&:day), @car.short_name])

Comment: Right now you're asuming that there's only one `StartDay` with that Travel id.

Comment: @GerardWesterhof, I assume there will be one start date for every travel with the same car.

Comment: Note that instead of `map{|x| x.day}`, you can do `map(&:day)`

Comment: @RailsGuy If you put it like that; I'd think that would be right. Still I don't know the model associations.

Comment: @Chowlett I was not sure map(&:day) will work in Rails 2.3, That's why I didn't suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
@start_day = StartDay.find(:first, :conditions => ["travel_id = ?", @travel.id], :order => "id DESC")
 @import_price = ImportPrice.find(:all, 
        :conditions => ["begin_date = ? and car_code = ?",
                        @start_day.day, @car.short_name])
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be; and I also took the chance to rewrite it a little bit depending on your model associations (if they're there):

```
def view
  @travel = Travel.find(params[:id])
  @car = Car.first.where(:id => @travel.car_id) #@travel.car? I don't know if that will work but it looks like it would
  @start_day = StartDay.where(:travel_id => @travel.id) # wouldn't @travel.start_days work?
  @import_price = ImportPrice.where("begin_date IN (?) and car_code = ?", 
    @start_day.map(&:day), @car.short_name)
end
```

Use `@start_day.map(&:day)` to get all the dates where you want to query upon.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for Error**:

```
StartDay.find(:all, :conditions => ["travel_id = ?", @travel.id])
```

You are getting this error because the code is returning you an array of all the objects (ie all the rows in your database table) which meet your condition. Even if there is just one entry in your database table that meets your condition, the return would be in a array format.

**Solution** :

One solution can be :

```
 @start_day = StartDay.find(:first, :conditions => ["travel_id = ?", @travel.id])
```

Yet another solution can be:

```
@import_price = ImportPrice.find(:all, 
        :conditions => ["begin_date in ? and car_code = ?",
                        @start_day.map{|x| x.day}, @car.short_name])
```